# How to extern const struct with vector members?

Tags: c++, struct, extern

I am splitting my code into declarations and definitions. I didn't get any problems until trying to do anything with this constant struct, consisting of vectors. Leaving this code in header leads to multiple definitions type of errors.

```
// Core.h:
const struct ConstData {
    vector<int> numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
} Constants;
```

I tried moving this code into cpp file and using *extern* with the struct in the header, but that didn't help. On use cases of struct fields in other files I was getting undeclared identifiers type of errors.

```
// Core.cpp:
const struct ConstData {
    vector<int> numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
} Constants;
```

```
// Core.h:
extern const struct ConstData Constants;
```

Tried putting the struct, with uninitialised fields, before the *extern*. Thought that might help, so compiler sees with what type of struct it's working and what fields it has. But that is considered redefinition, since I have same struct in cpp file.

```
// Core.h:
const struct ConstData {
    vector<int> numbers1;
    vector<int> numbers2;
};

extern const struct ConstData Constants;
```

```
// Core.cpp:
const struct ConstData {
    vector<int> numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
} Constants;
```

I'm kinda stuck at this point. Looking up how people are dealing with this issue didn't lead me to much success. In *extern* docs of Microsoft was said that *const* modifier changes linkage type (internal or external). So I tried all of the above again, but playing with the *const* at the same time — no progress on that. Maybe I missed something..

Hope I have supplied enough info and that community will be able to help me!

Comment: Microsoft's docs on *extern* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: You are redeclaring the entire `struct` in the implementation file. Why? It should be something like `extern const ConstData Constants { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 0, 10, 20, 30 } };` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```cpp
const struct ConstData {
    vector<int> numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
} Constants;
```

...declares both the structure type `ConstData` and the variable `Constants`. You cannot re-declare the structure in the `.cpp` file if you already declare it in the header file.

You want to split both declarations in the header and only initialize the variable in the `.cpp` file:

```
// Core.h
#include <vector>

struct ConstData {
    std::vector<int> numbers1;
    std::vector<int> numbers2;
};

extern const ConstData Constants;

// Core.cpp
#include <Core.h>

const ConstData Constants{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    { 0, 10, 20, 30 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a struct with static members and `std::array` for the elements. Since c++17 you can declare this in header file:

```cpp
#include <array>
struct ConstData {
    static constexpr std::array numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    static constexpr std::array numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
};
```

And use `ConstData::number1` / `ConstData::number2`.

Before `c++17` it is a bit more effort:

```cpp
// Header file:
struct ConstData {
    static constexpr std::array<int, 5> numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    static constexpr std::array<int, 5> numbers2 = { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
};

// c++-File
constexpr std::array<int,5> ConstData::numbers1;
constexpr std::array<int,5> ConstData::numbers2;
```

These are compile-time structures. So they appear 1:1 in memory. Using `std::vector` always allocates memory and copies the elements at runtime.

Comment: I was considering using static structures. Thanks for the example ^^